# Regex Get Words Between HTML Tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have this string :

```
<p><ins>Article </ins>Title</p> 

<p>Here&#39;s some sample text</p>
```

I'd like to get words neglecting html tags to array, ie

```
['Article','Title','Here&#39;s','some','sample','text']
```

I tried to create a regex, but it wont succeed. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the regex you got so far?

Comment: var res = str.match(/<[a-z]+>(.*?)<\/[a-z]+>/g).map(function(val){ 
   return val;
}

Comment: Regexes and HTML don’t mix very nicely. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/123681

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put them in a dummy `div` and get `innerText`

```js
var str = `<p><ins>Article </ins>Title</p> 
<p>Here&#39;s some sample text</p>`;

var div = document.createElement( "div" );
div.innerHTML = str; //assign str as innerHTML
var text = div.innerText; //get text only

var output = text.split( /\s+/ ); //split by one or more spaces including line feeds
console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a regex for this, you can simply use the browser's API:

```js
const html = "<p><ins>Article </ins>Title</p> <p>Here&#39;s some sample text</p>";
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = html;

// This will extract the text (remove the HTML tags)
const text = div.textContent || div.innerText || "";
console.log(text);

// Then you can simply split the string
const result = text.split(' ');
console.log(result);
```